# Android SearchAutocomplete into Fragment

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I'm new into android and i am trying to create an application that ask the ask its initial location and the destination location. (like google map)

The issue is that i am creating it into a fragment and as soon as i click on the search bar, my application crash "Unfortunately the application has stopped" with this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(java.util.List)'
>   on a null object reference

Here is my code into the fragment "SearchFragment"

```
String apikey = "vvfvsvsddsvsvdsvdsvsdDummyApiKey";
if (!Places.isInitialized()){
    Places.initialize(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), apikey);
}
placesClient = Places.createClient(this.getActivity());
try {
    // From Fragment
    final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, 
Place.Field.NAME));

    autocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
            final LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            Log.i("PlacesApi", "onPlaceSelected:" + latLng.latitude + "\n" + latLng.longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

        }
    });

    // To Fragment
    final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragmentTo = 
(AutocompleteSupportFragment) 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragmentTo);

    assert autocompleteSupportFragmentTo != null;
    autocompleteSupportFragmentTo.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, 
Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME));

    autocompleteSupportFragmentTo.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
            final LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            assert latLng != null;
            Log.i("PlacesApi", "onPlaceSelected:" + latLng.latitude + "\n" + latLng.longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

        }
    });
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error into the GooglePlaces Secction");
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you add your AutocompleteSupportFragment in activity?